# How to combine different Monad Stacks?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have 2 functions with "intersecting" interfaces:

```
type Config = (param1, param2)

runExe :: [String] -> ReaderT Config IO ExitCode
someAction :: [String] -> ReaderT Config (MaybeT IO) ()
```

Since both `runExe` and `someAction` carry the immutable Config, I want to pass it implicitly without doing "asking" explicitly. Something like the following:

```
 someAction params = monadConvertor runExe ["some" , "params"]
```

How do I implement `monadConvertor`?

As far as I understand monadConvertor needs to extract IO ExitCode then lift `guard (rc == ExitSuccess)`. But i don't know if it possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `monadConverter` should have the following type:

```
monadConverter :: ReaderT Config IO ExitCode -> ReaderT Config (MaybeT IO) ()
```

As you already wrote in your question, you only need to "extract" the `ExitCode`, and then "lift" `guard (rc == ExitCode)`, which you can do with the `lift` function. The problem is now that you cannot use the `ReaderT Config IO ExitCode` inside a `ReaderT Config (MaybeT IO) ()`. You can fix this by using [mapReaderT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v%3amapReaderT):

```
mapReaderT :: mapReaderT :: (m a -> n b) -> ReaderT r m a -> ReaderT r n b
```

Using that function, `monadReader` can be implemented as follows:

```
monadConverter :: ReaderT Config IO ExitCode -> ReaderT Config (MaybeT IO) ()
monadConverter action = do
  exitCode <- mapReaderT lift action
  lift $ guard (exitCode == ExitSuccess)
```

Here, `mapReaderT lift` has the type `ReaderT Config IO ExitCode -> ReaderT Config (MaybeT IO) ExitCode`.

Comment: Yes, it works great). But let me to note that there is no need to lift guard explicitly in this case.